# Fancytree lazyload: Why does empty result throw an error?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, fancytree

I have a Fancytree for displaying a directory structure with files in it. Therefor I use the lazyLoad functionality of Fancytree which already works well. That means, if I click on a directory, it loads the contents via an AJAX request.

If I have a directory without content to be loaded, my server-side script returns [] (as documented in Fancytree docs). I get the following error then:

TypeError: node.getLastChild(...) is undefined

The lines that throws the error is line 3016 in jquery.fancytree.js:

node.getLastChild().scrollIntoView(true, node);

Is this a Fancytree bug or have I done something wrong?

(using Firefox and Fancytree version 2.0.0-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should open an issue for this.
**edit** 
created this issue: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/163